# Weblogic JSON renderization

Tags: json, web-deployment, weblogic12c

I am using angularjs in a grails 2.4.4 application and in order to provide data to it, every request of my application has a JSON format response, like: 
`render object as JSON`

When I deploy it in Weblogic 12c, the respond is not returning the JSON correctly. I am obtaining a JSON that is not a JSON. This not happens in others servers.
For a better understanding look these image:

In Weblogic 12c I don't obtain a JSON object in the response

[image: the problem in weblogic12c]

Tomcat and Wildfly(Ok)

[image: In Tomcat and WildFly it runs OK]

Somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a tecnological answer. Instead, I installed the production version of Weblogic and in this case it works! I suppose, one of the production versions installed plugins that were missing in my old version. Regards